# geting input in one line array / list

Tags: python

How can I get an input like this in python3

The first input is = 2 and based on this first input I want to get 2 get new inputs

For example:

```
2 # how many inputs?
1 2 # 2 numbers inputs
```

or

```
3 # how many inputs?
3 5 8 # in one line getting 3 inputs
```

Here is another example:

```
4
6 8 7 9
```

How I can get in one line inputs based on the first input?

I tried to use map but with no luck

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
   x = map(int,input().split())
```

But the output is

```
if n is 2
1 2
```

Again asking for inputs because of `i = 0` getting `1 2` and `i = 1` again asking for input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you're running a loop n times and in each iteration you are picking up a whole line of input. Thus, at the end `x` contains the latest input line.
Instead you can read space separated input and store it into list directly.

```
n = int(input())
x = list(map(int,input().split()))
```

Although, if you expect that second line can contain more than `n` numbers, you can pick up first n numbers through

```
n = int(input())
x = list(map(int,input().split()))[:n]
```

Comment: yeah but what's point of n in here ?

Comment: @noobatmath no point. It represents input size which is required in languages like C etc. so that you can declare array with desired size upfront. Although if you want to look for only first `n` characters in second line, then you can modify as `x = list(map(int,input().split()))[:n]`

Answer (score 0):

If the inputs are provides as separate lines:

```
n = int(input())
x = [int(input() for _ in range(n)]
```

If the inputs are on one line:

```
n = int(input())
x = [int(number.strip()) for number in input().split()]
```

Comment: thanks but how i can append them to a list ? ` x = [int(input() for _ in range(n))test_list.append(x)] `

Comment: The code will result in a single list with all entries. I prefer list comprehension over the old fasshioned initialization of an empty list and a bunch of appends in a loop.\

Answer (score 0):

You need ANSI escape sequence. `\033[#A` moves the cursor up `#` lines.

Here's the code:

```
import os

n = int(input("How many inputs: "))

print()
prompt = ''
inputs = []
for _ in range(n):
    os.system(r'echo "\033[2A"')  # Go up 2 lines to account for \n during input
    inp = int(input(prompt))
    inputs.append(inp)
    prompt += f'{inp} '

print('inputs =', inputs)
```

Output:

```
How many inputs: 3
1 2 3
inputs = [1, 2, 3]
```

**NOTE**: This will only work in terminal.